# jQuery Regex for username doesn't work

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using the following code to test if the user has correctly written the username in an input field (id='username'). Unfortunately, the code fails to report an error when other special characters are used, i.e., ^, *, +, § etc are used.

For example:

> micky^
>
> ppppppp§°
>
> micky12-22

they all pass the test.

Unfortunately I have spent several days but I have failed to fix the problem.

The syntax of the username is:

1. First character = letter
2. Following chars = letter OR number OR _ (underscore) . (point) - (dash)
3. Minimum length 5 chars
4. Maximum length 20 chars

This is the code:

```
> var returncode = true; 
> var userinput = $('#username').val(); 
> var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{1}|[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]{4, 19}$/); 

> if(!pattern.test(userinput)) {    
>      returncode = false;
> }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{1}|[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]{4, 19}$/)
```

A regular expression literal is already a regular expression; you don't need to cast it again. `{1}` is redundant. `a-zA-Z0-9_` is also `\w`. `.` has no special meaning in character classes, and `-` at the end doesn't need to be escaped. The first `[a-zA-Z]` can just be `[a-z]` with the `i` flag, which sort of belongs, anyways. So with that out of the way:

```
/^[a-z]|[\w.-]{4,19}$/i
```

On to the actual problem. `^` and `$` are both options in the "or", so any username that starts with one letter or 4 to 19 letters, digits, underscores, periods or dashes works. Group the middle:

```
/^([a-z]|[\w.-]{4,19})$/i
```

… except, according to your description, you didn’t even mean to do that? It could just be:

```
/^[a-z][\w.-]{4,19}$/i
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, I wish I could know what you know on regular expressions. Btw, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
console.log(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/i.test('test'));
console.log(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/i.test('1testing'));
console.log(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/i.test('testing'));
console.log(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/i.test('micky^'));
console.log(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/i.test('ppppppp§°'));
console.log(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/i.test('micky12-22'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5x6k/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var returncode = true; 
 var userinput = $('#username').val(); 
 var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$/); 

 if(!pattern.test(userinput)) {    
      returncode = false;
 }
```

where

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]{4,19}$
   |        |________________Letters, numbers, dot and dash in remaining 
   |
Letter as start
```

It will work for sure.